# Is it possible to get String value back from its hash code?

Tags: java, string, hashcode

Java doc for method [String#hashCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29) says:

> Returns a hash code for this string. The hash code for a String object is computed as

```
 s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]
```

> using int arithmetic, where s[i] is the ith character of the string, n is the length of the string, and ^ indicates exponentiation. (The hash value of the empty string is zero.)

**Questions:**

- Is it possible to have same hash code for two string objects having different values? If yes then please share some examples.
- Is it possible to get String value back from its hash code?

I am not using it any where in code. I have just asked this question to know more about Java String class.

Comment: *Is it possible to have the same hash code for two string objects having different values?*  Yes.  *Is it possible to get String value back from its hash code?*  No.

Comment: A hash code is 32 bits long.  You can have strings that are thousands of bytes long.  There's no way to encode the string into the hash code uniquely.

Comment: Thanks a lot for examples. I was wrong that string object always returns a unique hash code.

Comment: Actually I am using a HashMap<String,Object> where key is a database query's hash code and value is the response to cache it in infinispan. But now it can create a problem where two different queries generating same hash code.

Comment: It used to be really bad, back around Java 1.0.2 or so.  Like any string longer than 10 characters was likely to have the same hash.

Comment: It's (sort of) reasonable to use hash code for a cache, if you (similarly to the internals of a hash table) check the "real" key value after using the hash for lookup.  If you get a mismatch you simply cache the new value (and "real" key) in place of the old.  This form of cache management is commonly used in hardware (for "page tables", etc).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it possible to have same hash code for two string objects having different values? If yes then please share some examples.

Here is a small sample of [randomly generated examples](http://ideone.com/e4ik20) of short strings with identical hash codes:

```
String 1   String 2   Common hash code
--------   --------   ----------------
VTBHKIGV - FLXCLLII        -1242944431
FPESRBAH - GNFWMYVA         1778061647
UYDHRTXL - HGCNRCBE         1509241566
VXQMFMDE - YMYXDWKK        -1553987354
VGWBSYRX - JZNQSUXK          700334696
```

Since multiple strings can share the same hash code, restoring the original from the hash is not possible.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it possible to have same hash code for two string objects having different values?

yes, how can you map infinite string possibilities  to `int` without it

> Is it possible to get String value back from its hash code?

no, read 1

Comment: please share some examples having same hash code with different values.

Comment: Java Strings are far from infinite: there are only (2^16-1) ^ (2^31-1) possibilities. (or rather a little more than that, since Strings are variable length)

Answer (score 1):

It's absolutely possible to have two different strings (or objects) with the same hash code. That's why we have collision handling. So in general it's not possible to get the string value back from the hash code. This is because the hash code value quickly overflows the 32-bit integer for strings longer than 4 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

assume your string is 2 characters long

c1,c2

your hash is 31*c1 + c2

can you think of different values that will map to the same hash?

it is worse in longer strings