# How to invoke method of an object whose reference id is stored in String?

Tags: java

I have the reference id of an object in the form of String. Now how can I call the method of that object by using reference id stored in String? When I am casting the String to the type of object, it is giving me `ClassCastException`  .So please help..thanx in advance..

Comment: What is this "reference ID" you are talking about?

Comment: reference id is the alpha numeric character which represents an object. When you print any object ,its reference id gets printed.

Comment: Are you talking about the hash code? You want to uniquely obtain an object back from its hashcode?

Comment: Aha. That's incorrect. When you print an object (which doesn't override `toString()`), it prints a concatenation of its class name, @ and its hash code.

Comment: @Tunaki ..yes dear

Comment: I guess he has called toString() on some class that doesn't override that. And now he wants to call a method on that very same object. Interesting idea.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22208490/is-it-possible-to-get-string-value-back-from-its-hash-code

Comment: Ok..I put it in another words..that combination of class,@ and its hashcode i have got stored into the String then how can I call the method of the object using that combination..

Comment: See the duplicate target. You can't. A hash code is a number that many objects of the same class may share. It's not a 1:1 identifier.

Comment: but the reference id is the identifier..I know that one can call the method using reference id but don't know how??

Comment: No, it's not a reference ID, it's not an identifier, and it's impossible to call a method using that string. You can only call methods if you have an actual object reference (a variable or a reflection of it), not with this "ID".